# Running rsync as a daemon for a local transfer

Tags: linux, rsync, nfs

My coworker is trying to talk me into running rsync as a daemon on my EM server. I'm currently using rsync to copy a NFS share on my storage cluster to USB external drives so the data can be reviewed else where.

The NFS share can get up to 200GBs+ in size. My coworker thinks that running rsync as a daemon on the system would improve performance, but it's my understanding that you run rsync as a daemon when you are doing remote transfers(a client/server relationship). Would running rysnc as a daemon improve performance when its a local transfer?

Comment: I would try it and see. Also, unless you using the incremental copy feature of rsync, `cp` will almost always be faster.

Comment: I'm using the incremental feature :)

Comment: Measure away then.